# index out of range exception when using tasks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task, async-await

I am getting "Index out of Range" exception when I am using the Async tasks on an array list. I checked all over stackoverflow and try different ways but none of them is working. Maybe I am missing something... Can someone please suggest.

```
        Task[] dataTasks = (from eachRow in ppcRowsCollection.Rows
                            select CreateDataRows(eachRow, subcTableArray, rowsArrayWithDefaultAndCommonValues)).ToArray();

private async Task<DataRow[]> CreateDataRows(PpcRow givenPpcRow, DataTable[] subcTableArray, DataRow[] rowsArrayWithDefaultAndCommonValues)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        DataTable[] subcTableArrayLocal = subcTableArray;
        DataRow[] defaultRowsArray = GetrowsArrayWithDefaultAndCommonValues(ref subcTableArrayLocal, ref rowsArrayWithDefaultAndCommonValues);
        SetOtherThanCommonColumnValues(ref defaultRowsArray, givenPpcRow);
        return defaultRowsArray;
    }
    ).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private DataRow[] GetrowsArrayWithDefaultAndCommonValues(ref DataTable[] subcTableArray, ref DataRow[] rowsArrayWithDefaultAndCommonValues)
{
    DataRow[] defaultRowsArray = subcTableArray.Select(x => x.NewRow()).ToArray(); //This is where I am getting EXCEPTION

    DataRow[] defaultRowsArrayCopy = defaultRowsArray;

    foreach (DataRow row in defaultRowsArrayCopy)
    {
        row.ItemArray = rowsArrayWithDefaultAndCommonValues
                            .Where(x => x.Table.TableName == row.Table.TableName)
                            .First()
                            .ItemArray;
    }
    return defaultRowsArrayCopy;
}
```

Stack Trace:

> at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)    at
>   System.Data.RecordManager.NewRecordBase()    at
>   System.Data.DataTable.NewRecord(Int32 sourceRecord)    at
>   System.Data.DataTable.NewRow(Int32 record)    at
>   System.Data.DataTable.NewRow()    at
>   PedWebService.<GetrowsArrayWithDefaultAndCommonValues>b__21(DataTable
>   x) in c:\Work\src\PedWebService.cs:line 2913    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   PedWebService.GetrowsArrayWithDefaultAndCommonValues(DataTable[]&
>   subcTableArray, DataRow[]& rowsArrayWithDefaultAndCommonValues) in
>   c:\Work\src\PedWebService.cs:line 2913

Comment: Can you please add the stacktrace for the exception to the question? That should provide more insight.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it Ryan. Here is the stack trace.

Comment: Try to add a variable and set its value to `subcTableArray.Select(x => x.NewRow())`. It looks like this might be null. Next time you may try to reproduce the issue with a simpler example prior to asking.

Comment: I tried adding the variable and stored the value of subcTableArray.Select(x => x.NewRow()). Its not null. It does have have value and I am creating this before calling async method.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish overall?

Comment: Here I am just creating a new row from each table in the "table array" and returning it as a array of DataRow's. I know that "Table" array has 3 tables as I created this before calling async method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `DataTable.NewRow()` on the same table in parallel. `DataTable` is not thread-safe, which is why that doesn't work.

If you're stuck with `DataTable`, I think the best option is to simply not use parallelization at all.

You could also try locking just the problematic operation (calling `NewRow()`), but I'm not sure that would be enough to make the code thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks svick. That was it. Once I locked the DataTable, this works fine. Unfortunately I stuck with datatable and don't have option. On MSDN I also noticed on Thread safety of data table that "This type is safe for multithreaded read operations. You must synchronize any write operations". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx